# Is it possible to pass html with external css styles through ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

after a long search for a solution, I am forced to write this post. I hope you can explain me what am I doing wrong.

I have files index.php, preview.php, saveToPdf.php and doc.html.

index.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

//some other code included jquery link
```

preview.php

```
// this file contain form, buttons and some function for loading, filling and sending datas.

<?php
   include 'index.php';
?>

// here is some html form

<button id="previewBtn">preview</button>
<button id="saveBtn">save</button>

<div id="content"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   fillDocs(){
       // filling the document
   }

   $('#previewBtn').click(function(){
      $('#content').load('./docs/doc.html', function(){
         fillDocs();
      });
   });

   $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
         request = $.ajax({

            url: "./saveToPdf.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'data' : $("#content").html(),
                   //other datas
            },
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        });
        
        request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(response);
            
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            console.log(textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
        });
   });
   
</script>
```

saveToPdf.php

```
// in this file I receive the data and store html content to pdf by MPDF lib.
// the problem is that this html content isn't formatted. It is plain html without css styles.
```

doc.html

```
// it is an html document with bootstrap classes
```

So what should I do to get the saved file with the correct formatting? It is working when I am using inline css styles but I would like to use bootstrap for this.

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html should tell you what you need to know, as far as I can see.

Comment: It is so funny. I read about it when I was using mpdf lib first time, but it was few years ago and know I just forgot about it. Thank you ADyson.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their [their docs](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html), you can set stylesheet data:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
```

Change `style.css` to the path of your CSS file.

Comment: Yes that is helpful, but the most important is a fact that MPDF support not all css attributes.